# Bash increment variable in for loop

Tags: bash

I have the following:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    a=0
for d in ./*/ ; do (
cd "$d"
((a++))
echo $a
); done
```

Which goes into each directory in my path, increments `a` and prints `a`. However, the output is always 1. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From bash(1):

> ```
>    (list) list is executed in a subshell environment (see  COMMAND  EXECU‐
>           TION  ENVIRONMENT below).  Variable assignments and builtin com‐
>           mands that affect the  shell's  environment  do  not  remain  in
>           effect  after  the  command completes.  The return status is the
>           exit status of list.
> ```

By simply removing the parenthesis you have around that block of code, you would have something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0
for d in ./*/
do
    ((a++))
    echo $a
done
```

(also slightly more conventionally formatted)

the result is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: The one liner quick and working `for d in \`seq 1 3\`;do echo $d ;done` to not pollute the interactive shell and without `$a` which is not needed. If needed: `a=0;for d in \`seq 1 3\`;do echo $a ;((a++));done`

Comment: @Timo How does this relate to the question, though? The question is about some set of files.

Comment: @Timo Ok, I restored the file pattern from the question as I guess that difference is what caused your confusion.

Comment: No worries, I got your idea. The question is about traversing a dir but more important about the increment. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Because you put the loop body in unnecessary ()'s which makes it execute in a subshell if I recall correctly.